# When applying modifiers to advantages/disadvantages, do you round up or down?

Tags: character-creation, gurps-4e

When you apply the percentage mods to an advantage or disadvantage in GURPS 4e, do you round up or down?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You round *up*, to a whole number. See "Modifiers", p. 101 in the Basic Set, top of the third column.